# Does the ret instruction add 4 to esp register?

Tags: assembly, x86, return, instructions, stack-pointer

Does the [`ret` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) cause "esp" register to be increased by 4?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it performs

```
pop eip
```

You can use

```
mov eax, [esp]
jmp eax
```

to avoid it.

EDIT: It's exactly what `ret` does. For example, `jmp rel_offet` is nothing than a hidden `add eip, offset`, or `jmp absolute_offset` is `mov eip, absolute_offset`. Sure there are differences in the way the processor treats them, but from programmer's point of view it's all that happens.

Also, there is a special form of `ret` : `ret imm8` that also adds this imm8 value to `esp` : for example a `__stdcall` function uses it to discard its parameters from the stack. Not to mention `retf` version, used in 16bit mode, that also pops the `cs` from the stack.

EDIT2:

```
pop register
```

means:

```
mov register, [esp]
add esp, 4
```

Comment: Doesn't eip cann't be modified directly?

Comment: If only the instruction:
ret
Does it change the value of register ESP.

Comment: @remainn

`jmp target_of_jump` is the way to modify eip directly (since `mov eip, target_of_jump` doesn't work).

For details on Intel 64 and IA32 assembly I recommend the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual": http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

BTW: Unless I am mistaken on ARM processors you can read/write the Program Counter directly (it's register 15 there).

Answer (score 2):

yes, because on the stack there is (well, there should be, see buffer overflow) the address to where resume the execution of the program. So ret means

```
pop ret_addr           ; pop deletes ret_addr from stack by adding 4 to esp
mov eip, ret_addr
```

which is

```
pop eip
```

just as ruslik said

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the processor is running in 32-bit protected mode.  In Real mode or 16-bit protected mode RET does a POP IP, which will cause an ADD ESP, 2 (instead of 4).