# seg fault when trying to return from function

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm kinda new with assembly, so i'm trying some different stuff just to varify that my knowledge is correct.

I tried to write this simple assembly code:

```
section .data
    string db "Your grade is %d", 0xa, 0

section .text
    global func
    extern printf

func:
    push 4
    push string
    call printf

    push dword [esp+8]
    add esp, 4
    jmp [esp-4]
```

which suppose to print `Your grade is 4`, but instead of adding 8 to `esp` and then use the `ret` command in the end, i tried something different. It does prints what i wanted, but then it falls (segFault).

Why? Can you explain that to me?

My thoughts: `[esp+8]` holds the return value, where we need to jump back at the end of the function. i pushed it (the return address) into the stack, raised the stack pointer back up and then jumped to `[esp-4]` which is where the return value i pushed two steps before is located.

Comment: I think you need to clean up the stack after printf with a add esp, 8 - otherwise the arguments will still be there

Comment: You should generally avoid addressing under the stack pointer as you do not own that memory. If you insist on not using a `ret` you can do `mov ecx, [esp+8]; add esp, 12; jmp ecx`. You need to balance the stack in either case.

Comment: Related re: your messing around with `jmp`: [What is the x86 "ret" instruction equivalent to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816685) (and other answers on that question that avoid tmp registers)