# x86 uica reports high uop count for ret instruction, does not agree with other sources

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

(one snippet is used to reduce # of traces linked, the actual throughput is irrelevant, only uop/instruction matters)
this sequence of instructions:

```
    ret

    ret 4

    pop rcx
    jmp rcx
```

generates the following trace on haswell uarch (as this is what I have, I will stick to it but similar traces happen on other uarches as well):
https://uica.uops.info/tmp/96c206fda86a42b6abcef52bd088ac13_trace.html

why do `ret` and `ret imm16` take so many uops? Especially compared to `pop jmp`?

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129107/what-is-the-x86-ret-instruction-equivalent-to) states that `pop jmp` and `ret` are equivalent which is indeed what is observed with benchmarking this code:

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    mov   rax, 0xFFFFFFF

.lp:
    call  .tst

    sub   rax, 1
    jge   .lp

    mov   eax, 0x3C
    xor   edi, edi
    syscall

.tst:
    pop   rcx
    jmp   rcx
;   ret
```

where version with `ret` takes about 1.3G cycles
and version with `pop jmp` takes about 1.3G cycles too

[xml file with instruction info](https://www.uops.info/xml.html) for `ret` without immiediate for `HSW` has this

```
<architecture name="HSW">
[...]
    ports="6*p06+6*p15+2*p23+2*p237+3*p4" uops="20" uops_MITE="4" uops_MS="6" uops_retire_slots="2"/>
```

which is not quite in the same order as uica shows but otherwise the same

[Fog's instruction tables page 250](https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) says `ret` uses p237 and p6 which is about the same as `pop jmp`

additionally ports reportedly used by `ret` are unexpected, in order:

```
1 * {p23} implies memory read  
6 * {p06 p15} suggests some arithmetic stuff  
3 * {p23(7) p4} implies memory **write**
```

I dont recall anything from [uica paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3524059.3532396) but I have **not** reread the paper very recently, just skimmed through it searching for keywords
I have not checked [source code](https://github.com/andreas-abel/uiCA/blob/master/uiCA.py) because AFAIK all instruction data is in the XML file mentioned above

so judging by that uica is clearly wrong unless there is a reason I dont know about
so the question is, is there such reason?

Comment: formatting near ports uses code snippet because SO insists that this is code snippet and yells about lack of indendation

Comment: @harold Thanks, i have missed that link. Now using slightly modified snipped so it can actually run in the loop and then replacing it with `pop jmp` produces significantly different results and agrees with uica.   

As for fixing return predictor stack I dont really know too but judging from linked answer, there is no fixup for ret (there may be mention in one of the mentioned articles, I havent read them) and even if, why would there be memory writes?

Comment: I dont think they would treat write from `mov` as coming from `ret` (even if, there is still only 1 `mov` but 3 uses of p4 by `ret` and the order does not agree) see this trace: https://uica.uops.info/tmp/e770cac44d6c46cb815d7a1361dbccb2_trace.html

Comment: uiCA uses data from https://uops.info/ measurements.  Those measurements are probably bogus for `ret`.  I think they're counting uops executed and issued over a whole loop, so branch mispredicts can inflate the count.  (Many of those uops don't retire.)  Their test loops (https://uops.info/html-tp/SKL/RET_NEAR-Measurements.html) use RIP-relative LEA, `mov [rsp], rax`, and `ret`.  (So the actual stack doesn't balance either, since they don't use push).

Comment: yup, retired uop count is almost precisely the same for both versions of their benchmark (`pop + jmp` and `ret` modified to not cause seg fault because of that stack issue you mentioned  :P) with much higher branch misprediction rate for `ret` so I think that concludes the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it's not useful to have `ret` in a block you're measuring with uiCA; it treats your code as a loop body whether or not it ends with a `jcc` back to the top, and whether or not it contains unconditional jumps.  (If there's no jump, it's as if you were going to unroll the loop body, although for JCC-erratum and uop-cache purposes it just uses the addresses of the one copy, as if there was a jump that executed for free.)

---

**uiCA uses data from https://uops.info/ measurements. Those measurements don't reflect normal usage of `ret` paired with `call`, only using `ret` alone in a loop as a general indirect jump.**  `ret` is hard to micro-benchmark on its own, especially in a benchmark framework that wants to test contiguous snippets of code inside loops, so there's nowhere to put a `call` to a separate `ret`.  (Except maybe as part of the "setup" code which nanobench allows; it could contain a `ret` that gets jumped during actual entry to the loop. But uops.info doesn't currently do that; [@AndreasAbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10461973/andreas-abel) might be interested in improving the `ret` microbenchmarks?)

I **think Agner Fog's measurement on Haswell of `ret` decoding as 1 micro-fused uop for ports `p237 p6` is correct**; that matches my measurements on Skylake<sup>1</sup>.  (Except p7 is almost certainly not right, probably a typo or copy/paste error in his spreadsheet.  Port 7 is a store-address execution unit only, it can't run loads.)

---

The uops.info numbers for `ret_near` (https://uops.info/html-instr/RET_NEAR.html) on Haswell are

- 28.91 cycle actual measured throughput, which is very slow, **probably from branch mispredicts.  That will throw off any uop counts other than retired**, since uops on the wrong path still get issued and executed in the shadow of the mispredict.  The counters for events like `uops_dispatched_port.port_6` don't distinguish between uops that go on to retire vs. those that get discarded.  This isn't a problem for microbenchmarking most instructions since the benchmark loop predicts perfectly.
- 2 front-end uops / 20 back-end uops, for ports `6*p06+6*p15+2*p23+2*p237+3*p4`.  Obviously way too high; we know ret isn't that slow when used normally (paired with a `call`).

uops.info's test loops (e.g. https://uops.info/html-tp/HSW/RET_NEAR-Measurements.html) use RIP-relative LEA to get a "return address" which it stores with `mov` instead of `push`.

```
# uops.info microbenchmark loop body for ret_near, unroll_count=500
   0:   48 8d 05 05 00 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x5]        # 0xc
   7:   48 89 04 24             mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
   b:   c3                      ret  
      lea_target:   # ret jumps here
```

Using `mov` instead of `push` means the RSP stack doesn't balance.  And mixing explicit `[rsp]` with a stack operation like `ret` that implicitly modifies RSP means the [stack engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture) will have to insert a stack-sync uop before every `mov`.  This might be the MS (microcode sequencer) uop.  This is a true extra cost for this loop, but also gets amplified by mispredicts.

---

**On Skylake, when the return-predictor stack is empty, `ret` falls back to normal indirect-branch prediction.  But earlier CPUs didn't, I think.**  (This matters for Spectre mitigation, IIRC making retpolines not 100% reliable if pre-emption happens in the middle of a retpoline or something.)  uops.info measured `ret` throughput at ~10 cycles on SKL, improved from ~29 cycles on Haswell and ~31 on Sandybridge, probably for that reason.  Ice Lake is back up to ~31, Alder Lake P-cores are down to 2.17 cycles per `ret` with the same loop.  (Perhaps Ice Lake dropped the fallback to normal indirect branch prediction but Alder Lake brought it back?  Or something else is going on, like maybe some branches aliased each other in the predictors in Ice Lake.)

Anyway, `ret` trying to use a non-existent prediction from an underflowed predictor-stack could lead to it mispredicting most of the time, with disastrous consequences.  The per-port uop breakdowns for HSW and earlier are nonsense on uops.info, but somewhat plausible for SKL and later.  Still inflated probably from stack-sync uops and maybe imperfect branch prediction, since there still seems to be a store getting counted until Alder Lake.

---

##### Footnote 1: Skylake measurements of `call/ret` pairs

My measurements on Skylake are that a `call rel32`/`ret` pair is 3 fused-domain uops, 5 unfused-domain uops that need execution units.  uops.info and Agner Fog agree that `call rel32` alone is 2 front-end uops that run as 3 unfused-domain uops.  (Jump and store-address+store-data).  That leaves `ret` as the expected 1 fused-domain uop: an indirect jump micro-fused with a load.  I expect Agner Fog did something like this to measure `ret`.

I put one or two `call test` in a tight loop (dec/jnz) to run under `perf stat` in a static executable, where `test: ret` was defined later.  All the ALU uops were port 6.  Load/store were a mix of ports 2,3,7.  (Of course the port 7 uops are only from `call`)

https://uops.info/ where measured SKL's `ret_near` alone at 2 front-end, 7 back-end.  (Perhaps the port breakdown is including extra mis-speculated `mov` stores from their test loop.)

```
; testloop.asm   - static executable for Linux
default rel
%use smartalign
alignmode p6, 64

global _start
_start:

    mov     ebp, 100000000
align 64
.loop:
    call test
    call test
    dec ebp
    jnz .loop
.end:

    xor edi,edi
    mov eax,231   ; __NR_exit_group  from /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h
    syscall       ; sys_exit_group(0)

align 32        ; in a separate 32-byte block to improve uop-cache hit rate, not that it matters much
test:
  ret
```

```
    ## on my i7-6700k Skylake, Linux 6.5 / perf 6.5
$ nasm -felf64 testloop.asm
$ ld -o testloop testloop.o
$ taskset -c 1 perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,idq.mite_uops,branch-misses  ./testloop

 Performance counter stats for './testloop':

            282.37 msec task-clock                       #    0.998 CPUs utilized             
                 0      context-switches                 #    0.000 /sec                      
                 0      cpu-migrations                   #    0.000 /sec                      
                 1      page-faults                      #    3.541 /sec                      
     1,100,001,492      cycles                           #    3.896 GHz                       
       600,000,098      instructions                     #    0.55  insn per cycle            
       700,089,165      uops_issued.any                  #    2.479 G/sec                     
     1,100,088,709      uops_executed.thread             #    3.896 G/sec                     
         8,413,976      idq.mite_uops                    #   29.798 M/sec                     
                 8      branch-misses                                                         

       0.282836215 seconds time elapsed

       0.282460000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

Commenting out one of the `call` instructions reduces the counts as expected, 3 front-end uops per iter, 5 back-end.  The dec/jnz is just 1 front-end / 1 back-end uop, for a total of 4 and 6 per iteration.

```
; with only one call in the loop
            120.58 msec task-clock                       #    0.996 CPUs utilized             
       463,605,997      cycles                           #    3.845 GHz                       
       400,000,049      instructions                     #    0.86  insn per cycle            
       400,041,809      uops_issued.any                  #    3.318 G/sec                     
       600,041,674      uops_executed.thread             #    4.976 G/sec                     
       134,054,953      idq.mite_uops                    #    1.112 G/sec
```

With counters for `uops_dispatched_port.port_0,uops_dispatched_port.port_1,uops_dispatched_port.port_5,uops_dispatched_port.port_6` and `uops_dispatched_port.port_2,uops_dispatched_port.port_3,uops_dispatched_port.port_7` in two separate runs, we can see the distribution:

```
# 2 call/ret pairs + dec/jnz

             5,619      uops_dispatched_port.port_0      #   19.750 K/sec                     
             7,637      uops_dispatched_port.port_1      #   26.843 K/sec                     
             8,827      uops_dispatched_port.port_5      #   31.025 K/sec                     
       500,099,429      uops_dispatched_port.port_6      #    1.758 G/sec                     

       164,323,545      uops_dispatched_port.port_2      #  581.175 M/sec                     
       135,457,372      uops_dispatched_port.port_3      #  479.082 M/sec                     
       100,224,734      uops_dispatched_port.port_7      #  354.472 M/sec
```

I don't know where those thousands of uops for ports 0, 1, and 5 are coming from.  None of the instructions this program runs in user-space can run on them.  Unless there's some kind of stack-sync thing when interrupts happen.

Comment: Also related re: return-address prediction and the internal fixups CPUs have to do on discovering a mispredict: https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/ - a `ret` on a mis-speculated path of execution would mess up the RAS predictor, so the CPU tries to repair that.  IDK if that takes any uops, though; it's probably dedicated hardware, not a microcode assist which would make branch recovery even slower.