# gdb addresses: 0x565561f5 instead of 0x41414141

Tags: c, gdb

I want to try a buffer overflow on a c program. I compiled it like this `gcc -fno-stack-protector -m32 buggy_program.c` with gcc. If i run this program in gdb and i overflow the buffer, it should said 0x41414141, because i sent A's. But its saying 0x565561f5. Sorry for my bad english. Can somebody help me?

This is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[64];

    printf("Type in something: ");
    gets(buffer);
}
```

```
Starting program: /root/Downloads/a.out 
Type in something: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x565561f5 in main ()
```

I want to see this:

```
Starting program: /root/Downloads/a.out 
Type in something: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in main ()
```

Comment: why do you think it is strange? whre is the code?

Comment: All you showed here is the disassembly. This doesn't tell you where the function will return to.

Comment: Try to enable ASLR in gdb with `set disable-randomization off`.

Comment: regarding: `gets(buffer);`   The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest versions of C.  Your compiler should have told you this.  Suggest using `fgets()` (which has different parameters from `gets()`)

Comment: the input of all those 'A's resulted in the overflow of the buffer: `char buffer[64];`   overflowing the buffer results in undefined behavior.  And that buffer is declared on the stack, so the stack is clobbered. So anything can happen.

Comment: But in other bof applications it is working perfectly, and I'm wondering what I've done wrong. This program is exact the same from www.exploit-exercises.com/protostar/stack5 (The site is currently down) with minimal changes. It should say 0x41414141.

Answer (score 1):

Modern operating systems use address-space-layout-randomization ASLR to make this stuff not work quite so easily.

I remember the controversy when it was first started. ASLR was kind of a bad idea for 32 bit processes due to the number of other constraints it imposed on the system and dubious security benefit. On the other hand, it works great on 64 bit processes and almost everybody uses it now.

You don't know where the code is. You don't know where the heap is. You don't know where the stack is. Writing exploits is hard now.

Also, you tried to use 32 bit shellcode and documentation on a 64 bit process.

On reading the updated question: Your code is compiled with frame pointers (which is the default). This is causing the ret instruction itself to fault because esp is trashed. ASLR appears to still be in play most likely it doesn't really matter.

Comment: And how can i get this to a 32bit process?

Comment: @bitfriends: That's this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake

Comment: Thanks! But how can i get when i type AAAA the 0x41414141? Its says just the return adress: 0x565561f5.

Comment: ASLR doesn't explain why the address causing the segfault is not `0x41414141` as the return address on the stack should have been overwritten with `0x41414141`. ASLR makes it hard to know where you want to jump to when you can overwrite `$EIP`.

Comment: @Steve: In v1 of the post, you can clearly see that `gdb` is reporting the address of the instruction that tried to return to unmapped memory. So anyway, the post has been edited away from my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid that ASLR is not the answer from v1 of the post. It is a corrupted stack pointer which means that when the `ret` instruction is executed (which is essentially a `pop $eip`) the attempt to pop fails.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the address at which the process segfaulted shows the relevant line in the disassembled code:

> gdb a.out <<EOF
>   set logging on
>   r < inp
>   disassemble main 
>   x/i $eip
>   p/x $esp

Produces the following output:

> (gdb) Starting program: .../a.out < in
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
>   0x08048482 in main (argc=, argv=) at tmp.c:10 10  } 
>   (gdb) Dump of assembler code for function main:
>   0x08048436 <+0>:  **lea 0x4(%esp),%ecx**
>   0x0804843a <+4>:  **and $0xfffffff0,%esp**
>   0x0804843d <+7>:  pushl -0x4(%ecx)
>   0x08048440 <+10>: push %ebp
>   0x08048441 <+11>: mov %esp,%ebp
>   0x08048443 <+13>: push %ebx
>   0x08048444 <+14>: **push %ecx**
>   0x08048445 <+15>: sub $0x40,%esp
>   0x08048448 <+18>: call
>   0x8048370 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
>   0x0804844d <+23>: add $0x1bb3,%ebx
>   0x08048453 <+29>: sub $0xc,%esp
>   0x08048456 <+32>: lea -0x1af0(%ebx),%eax
>   0x0804845c <+38>: push %eax
>   0x0804845d <+39>: call 0x8048300 
>   0x08048462 <+44>: add $0x10,%esp
>   0x08048465 <+47>: sub $0xc,%esp
>   0x08048468 <+50>: lea -0x48(%ebp),%eax
>   0x0804846b <+53>: push %eax
>   0x0804846c <+54>: call 0x8048310 
>   0x08048471 <+59>: add $0x10,%esp
>   0x08048474 <+62>: mov $0x0,%eax
>   0x08048479 <+67>: lea -0x8(%ebp),%esp
>   0x0804847c <+70>: **pop %ecx**
>   0x0804847d <+71>: pop %ebx
>   0x0804847e <+72>: pop %ebp
>   0x0804847f <+73>: **lea -0x4(%ecx),%esp**
>   => 0x08048482 <+76>:  ret
>   End of assembler dump.
>   (gdb) => 0x8048482 : ret
>   (gdb) $1 = 0x4141413d
>   (gdb) quit

The failing statement is the `ret` at the end of `main`. The program fails, when `ret` attempts to load the return-address from the top of the stack. The produced executable stores the old value of `esp` on the stack, before aligning to word-boundaries. When `main` is completed, the program attempts to restore the `esp` from the stack and afterwards read the return-address. However the whole top of the stack is compromised, thus rendering the new value of the stack-pointer garbage (`$1 = 0x4141413d`). When `ret` is executed, it attempts to read a word from address 0x4141413d, which isn't allocated and produces as segfault.

**Notes**

The above disassembly was produced from the code in the question using the following compiler-options:

> -m32 -fno-stack-protector -g -O0

Comment: Do I have to add $1 = 0x4141413d?

Comment: @bitfriends no. That's the value of the esp-register when the program crashes. The problem is that the program as it is compiled attempts to restore the esp-registers value from the stack at the end of main. However the stack was compromised by the bufferoverflow. In the end this will most likely boil down to using an older compiler (I'm currently looking into that, but if anyone is faster, feel free to add the info either to the answer or as a comment).

Comment: So the compiler is the problem?

Comment: @bitfriends yup. More specifically the configuration. The overflow messes with the alignment-functionality.

Comment: @bitfriends a general advice on the topic you're currently working: there are plenty of books about hacking that provide their own environment, which is already configured to avoid such issues as the above.

Comment: Here is a link: https://alternativeto.net/software/gnu-compiler-collection/

Comment: This is the right answer. ASLR is definitely not the cause of the problem here. The `ret` instruction effectively does `pop eip`. The `pop` instruction needs to read the memory at `esp` which has been corrupted. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292447/does-ret-instruction-cause-esp-register-added-by-4

Answer (score 1):

So guys, i found a solution:
Just compile it with `gcc 3.3.4`
`gcc -m32 buggy_program.c`